# Understanding the role of a pull-up resistor

Tags: transistors

I am trying to understand the role of the transistor R11 in the following schematic:

[image]

The schematic simply generates a pulse at R5 when the switch is pressed.

If I understand correctly R11 is what one calls a "pull-up resistor" and it ensures that we can reliably switch on and switch off the circuit using the transistor. More precisely the presence of R11 (at a smaller resistance) allows us to reliably connect R4 + C2 to the ground. It makes sense that this is helpful.

But I don't understand why this is necessary. For instance is it possible to remove R11 from the schematic and connect directly R4 + C2 as the collector of the transistor?

Is it correct for me to assume that this will not work because the voltage across the capacitor will be sometimes negative? And as a result the transistor would not act like a switch but more like an amplifier?.

I'm sorry if these questions are trivial, I'm still learning about transistors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit is an edge detector. When SW3 is pressed, it generates a brief 5 V pulse at Q3's Collector, Q3[c]. The pulse generation is centred around R4 and C2.

At rest with Q4 off, R11 pulls Q4[c] high and also R4 drives Q3[b] to switch on Q3 and drive Q3[c] low (around 0.3 V). Q3[b]->Q3[e] acts like a forward-biased diode so Q3[b] is at around 0.7 V. So C2 has 5 V at its 'bottom' end and 0.7 V at its 'top' end, charging it to -4.3 V.

At the moment SW3 is pressed, Q4 switches on and Q4[c] drops to 0.3 V or thereabouts. Vc2 is still -4.3 V so Q3[b] tries to instantaneously go to -4 V. The 2N3904 has a Veb max of 6 V i.e. a Vbe min or -6 V so this is OK but not ideal. C4 then charges through the connection to 5 V by R4.

However, when R4/C2 reaches about 0. 7V, Q3[b] conducts to switch on Q3 and its sort-of-diode (base diode) within Q3[b]->Q3[e] keeps Q3[b] clamped at 0.7 V. C2 has 0.3 V at its 'bottom' end and 0.7 V at its 'top end', so it stays charged to 0.4 V.

Holding down SW3 then does nothing more to Q3, which was briefly switched off by the pressing of SW3 but now stays on. When SW3 is released, Q4 goes off and Q4[c] is pulled to 5 V by R11. C2 is charged to 0.4 V so C2/R4 would go to 5.4 V but the Q3 base diode keeps its top at 0.7 V and is charges instead to -4.3 V, back to the rest state. Q3[b] doesn't fall below 0.7 V during this so Q3 stays on.

R11 is therefore the source of drive current from the Q4 stage. Without it, Q4 could deliver (a) a low sink current conducted down to 0 V or (b) a high-impedance 'floating' connection i.e. nothing. Adding R11 lets Q4 source current when on and sink current when off. As the R11 value is a tenth of R4, it has a much smaller effect on the time constant of C2 than R4 has.

Without R11, C2 'bottom' would be left floating when Q4 is off and could not charge to -4.3 V. Instead, C2 would stay charged, theoretically to 0.4 V. So R11 is essential for the circuit to clear itself on an SW3 release, ready for the next SW3 press.

Note that the transistor voltages given above are approximates.

Answer (score 6):

Drawn better, it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft5s0s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Within the left-box, you have a simple BJT used as a saturated switch. And on the right-box you have yet another such BJT used as a saturated switch. The trick, here, is that these are connected only via a capacitor!

With \$SW_3\$ is normally grounded, \$Q_4\$ is normally ***off*** and before \$SW_3\$ is engaged, the circuit powers up and \$R_{11}\$ and \$R_4\$ both "pull up" on each side of capacitor \$C_2\$, hauling both sides to \$+5\:\text{V}\$. But this is the same thing as saying that there is \$0\:\text{V}\$ across capacitor \$C_2\$. Yes? So, by default, there's no voltage across \$C_2\$.

Also, \$R_4\$ is supplying base current to \$Q_3\$. So \$Q_3\$ is ***on***, by default. This means that **OUT** is close to ground, or near \$0\:\text{V}\$, by default.

When \$SW_3\$ is changed to the \$+3\:\text{V}\$ rail, it activates \$Q_4\$ causing it to suddenly pull down on its collector and therefore ground **A**. However, right at this moment in time please don't forget that there is also \$0\:\text{V}\$ across \$C_2\$. (See above paragraph.) So, it follows that **B** will equal **A** right at this moment. (This will change. But at the immediate instant the switch is changed, this is true.) This causes \$Q_3\$ to be turned ***off***. And when that happens, \$R_5\$ is able to immediately pull **OUT** to \$+5\:\text{V}\$.

Now, this is what happens immediately. But if you hold \$SW_3\$ to this new state, then \$R_4\$ will start supplying current (as it now has \$+5\:\text{V}\$ across it.) This current will, at first, just start charging up the right-end of \$C_2\$ (the left end is held close to ground by \$SW_3\$ in its new state.) So as \$C_2\$ charges upward, the base voltage for \$Q_3\$ also starts rising upward. At some point, \$C_2\$ is sufficiently charged to have enough voltage across it that \$Q_3\$ is re-activated and pulls down on its collector causing **OUT** to return back near to \$0\:\text{V}\$.

If you keep \$SW_3\$ held, **OUT** will fully return to its \$0\:\text{V}\$ output. So from the perspective of **OUT**, you will see a "rising towards \$+5\:\text{V}\$, but short-duration, pulse." Once \$C_2\$ charges up enough, \$Q_3\$'s base pulls away most of the current in \$R_4\$ and the charging of \$C_2\$ halts. And there it sits until you release \$SW_3\$.

Once you release \$SW_3\$, \$Q_4\$ turns back ***off*** and then \$R_{11}\$ can now pull upward on the left end of \$C_2\$. Since \$C_2\$ will only have about \$+700\:\text{mV}\$ across it (the right end is more positive than the left), the base of \$Q_3\$ will momentarily rise to \$+5.7\:\text{V}\$. \$Q_3\$ is already ***on*** and this voltage is way, way too much for the base-emitter junction of \$Q_3\$, so there will be a momentary high current pulse into the base of \$Q_3\$ as well as into the \$+5\:\text{V}\$ supply rail. But capacitor \$C_2\$ will also be rapidly discharged and will return to a state with \$0\:\text{V}\$ across it. The circuit is now back to where it was before.

The time period for the high-going pulse width would normally be proportional to \$\left(R_4+R_{11}\right)\cdot C_2\$. And in your circuit, this is on the order of about \$110\:\mu\text{s}\$. But it will likely be less than that. There is a significant added effect of the base-emitter junction of \$Q_3\$ and the resulting partial charged voltage involved. So it will always be less than that. I'll avoid worrying about the math, for now.

Comment: Thanks to both of you and TonyM for answering my question in such detail. I was wondering about the following: Once Q4 is activated, can't I compute the voltage at the base of Q3 by simply viewing the R4 + C2 circuit as a voltage divider ? In this case ignoring the 0.2 voltage drop from collector - emitter of Q4 I'm getting that the voltage at the base of Q3 is equal to 5 * (1 - cos(10^4 t)) and this is capped off at 0.7v by the diode from base to emitter of Q3.  In particular the pulse depends only on R_4 and not R_11. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @blaber In the Laplace domain, it would act like a \$\frac{\frac1{R\,C}}{s+\frac1{R\,C}}\$ divider, I suppose. Only if you ignored \$Q_3\$'s base. But you can't ignore the base. So it's much better to "see it" (my opinion) the way I described it. Perhaps if you spent more time discussing your own thinking (in your question, not in comments because there's no space to do so in comments), I might see your perspective well enough to either agree or disagree more meaningfully.

Comment: I removed the further question here because I understood it was incorrect!